# numba/npyufunc/omppool.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, llvm, numba

Experts,

I am trying to install numba using pip inside a virtual python environment. I am encountering the following error:

Error log:

```
cc: numba/cuda/cudadrv/_extras.c
    cc -shared -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector build/temp.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/cuda/cudadrv/_extras.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/cuda/cudadrv/_extras.so
    building 'numba.npyufunc.omppool' extension
    C compiler: cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC

    compile options: '-I/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c'
    extra options: '-fopenmp -std=c++11'
    cc: numba/npyufunc/omppool.cpp
    cc: numba/npyufunc/gufunc_scheduler.cpp
    numba/npyufunc/omppool.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
    #include <omp.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    numba/npyufunc/omppool.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
    #include <omp.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: Command "cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -I/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c numba/npyufunc/omppool.cpp -o build/temp.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/npyufunc/omppool.o -fopenmp -std=c++11" failed with exit status 1
error
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-install-g3ckpog3/numba
Removed build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-21vj3szg'
Command "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-g3ckpog3/numba/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-lf_sxfnx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include/site/python3.6/numba" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-g3ckpog3/numba/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 366, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 791, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-g3ckpog3/numba/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-lf_sxfnx/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include/site/python3.6/numba" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-g3ckpog3/numba/
```

But `omp.h` is present in `/usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/omp.h`.

Any help to troubleshoot/fix this issue is much appreciated. I am running `FreeBSD 12` and `python3.6`. I have softlinked `llvm7` as the default, as an information of that would be of help.

I think, makefile is looking for `omp.h` in a location different from where actually it is. If so, is there a way I can pass the path as an argument during `pip` installation?

**FOLLOW-UP :**
Setting `CPPFLAGS` as advised by @hoefling does solve the above issue. However, the next error is as follows:

```
 C compiler: cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -I /usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/ -fPIC

    compile options: '-I/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c'
    extra options: '-fopenmp -std=c++11'
    cc: numba/npyufunc/omppool.cpp
    cc: numba/npyufunc/gufunc_scheduler.cpp
    c++ -shared -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector -I /usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/ build/temp.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/npyufunc/omppool.o build/temp.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/npyufunc/gufunc_scheduler.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/npyufunc/omppool.so -fopenmp
    building 'numba.npyufunc.workqueue' extension
    C compiler: cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -I /usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/ -fPIC

    compile options: '-I/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c'
    cc: numba/npyufunc/workqueue.c
    cc: numba/npyufunc/gufunc_scheduler.cpp
    numba/npyufunc/workqueue.c:22:10: fatal error: 'alloca.h' file not found
    #include <alloca.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    numba/npyufunc/workqueue.c:22:10: fatal error: 'alloca.h' file not found
    #include <alloca.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: Command "cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -I /usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/ -fPIC -I/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c numba/npyufunc/workqueue.c -o build/temp.freebsd-12.0-RELEASE-p2-amd64-3.6/numba/npyufunc/workqueue.o" failed with exit status 1
error
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-install-fbsigyza/numba
Removed build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-0v_6_gji'
Command "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-fbsigyza/numba/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-pcr7ap84/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include/site/python3.6/numba" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-fbsigyza/numba/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 366, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 791, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "/home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-fbsigyza/numba/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-pcr7ap84/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/russellb/py_devel/pyPlay/include/site/python3.6/numba" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-fbsigyza/numba/
```

I have two `alloca.h` at the following locations:

```
/usr/src/contrib/ofed/libibverbs/alloca.h
/usr/src/cddl/compat/opensolaris/include/alloca.h
```

I don't know which is the correct one to be included.

Thanks for all your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Linux

`omp.h` is usually part of the `gcc` compiler, e.g. on Ubuntu it's installed with

```
$ sudo apt install libgcc-7-dev
```

#### FreeBSD

The header is provided by `devel/openmp`. You can install it with:

```
$ sudo pkg install devel/openmp
```

This will place `omp.h` into `/usr/local/include`, which should be under default include dirs.

#### Custom include

If you want to append the header under a custom include dir, use the `CPPFLAGS`/`CFLAGS` environment variables:

```
$ CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/" pip install numba
```

---

For the second error, I suppose `numba` was not written with FreeBSD in mind (also not sure whether CUDA and FreeBSD play nice in general). Maybe [open an issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new/choose)? I suppose the patch proposal for [`numba/npyufunc/workqueue.c`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/npyufunc/workqueue.c#L22) should be

```c
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
+#if !defined (__FreeBSD__)
 #include <alloca.h>
+#endif
 #define NUMBA_PTHREAD
 #endif
```

Other than that, try including the second one (`/usr/src/cddl/compat/opensolaris/include/alloca.h`).

Comment: Thank you @hoefling. I have `gcc8` installed and I have the `omp.h` located in the location you've specified. I tried setting `CPPFLAGS` as you suggested. But, `pip3` is not respecting that and the same error results. Default `omp.h` location is `/usr/local/include/omp.h` which is no different from '/usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/omp.h` ( I have diffed them )

Comment: Managed to get that error past with setting `CPPFLAGS` at `.basrc`. However, there is another error: I am editing my question to include the new error.

Comment: Hmm, passing the `CPPFLAGS` directly to the `pip install` command should be no different than putting it into `.bashrc`. You can also export the env var so it's applied to all commands in the current session: `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/llvm70/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/"` or `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/"`, then calling `pip install numba` should respect the changed env.

Comment: As for your second issue, I suspect this is an issue in `numba` - maybe it would be good to open an issue (check the update in the answer).

Comment: No luck with `alloca.h` path inclusion. After looking for `CUDA` and `FreeBSD`, I gained a feeling that the combo is not workable yet and I don't see any thing could happen in the near feature. However, I am going to open an issue. Thanks @hoefling. Appreciated your help.